# What is the maximum number of terms I should sum for a band limited signal?

Tags: fourier-series

I'm using this formula to calculate each point on a band limited square wave:

[image]

For any given frequency f, what is the maximum number of terms I can sum without my output function containing a frequency that exceeds a given frequency fMax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frequency of the first term is $f$, the second $3f$, the third is $5f$ and so on.  Keep going until you hit $f_{max}$